# What is the difference between headings and useheadings in the pagestyle command?

Tags: header-footer, classicthesis, scrpage2

I use `classicthesis` and a warning suggests me to replace

```
\pagestyle{headings}
```

with

```
\pagestyle{useheadings}
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **classicthesis** package loads **scrpage2**, which specifies different conventions than the standard classes: in order to use its automatic features, the `headings` page style should be changed into one provided by the **scrpage2** package.

See chapter 4 in the manual for KoMa Script.

Comment: From the [manual](http://ftp.uniroma2.it/TeX/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/scrguien.pdf): [...] it may be necessary to shift back also to a style provided by the document class. It might appear that this should be done with `\page style{headings}`, but this has the disadvantage that commands `\automark` and `\manualmark` do not function as expected. For this reason one should shift back to the original styles using `\page style{useheadings}`, which chooses the correct page styles automatically for both manual and automatic running headings.